# K&R C Chapter 5 dcl issue

Tags: c, input, recursive-descent

I've gotten to the end of chapter 5 of K&R C second edition, which is about pointers. I've done ok and understood everything so far, but for some reason I'm struggling to understand what exercise 5-18 is asking:
"Make dcl recover from input errors"

Sounds simple enough, but how far is the question expecting me to go? Just missing parentheses, lack of newlines, etc? I would appreciate knowing how others have solved this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see some specific examples about how this is solved:

- [example1](http://www.c-program-example.com/2012/02/k-r-c-programs-exercise-5-18.html).
- [example2](http://uthcode.sarovar.org/c/allprogs/dcl-errorec.c).
- [example3](http://privetmiru.blogspot.fi/2013/09/exercise-518-make-dcl-recover-from.html).

There are few more examples if you look in Google.

Comment: Thank you - example three showed me I was looking at it the wrong way - attempting to correct the errors rather than just continue execution. This is probably why I couldn't wrap my head around it :-)